# Hover effect on parents child's child

Tags: html, css

I want on hover on parent, child's child's **TEXT ONLY** turn red too. Is it possible ?

```
<div id="row">o
    <div id="col" class="col">o o
        <div id="colChild" class="col-child">o o o Turn Me Red</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#row {
    width: 300px;
    height:100px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
#row:hover {
    background-color:pink
}
#col{
    padding:5px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
#colChild {
    padding:5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NHbn8/235/

**Out of Context information** 
In real these are rows of a table and they will also on select keep there hover state (but it's out of context for now)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NHbn8/237/

Answer (score 3):

Use this on hover parent `#row:hover > .col > .col-child{background:red;}`

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/33mhdju6/

```
#row {
  width: 300px;
  height:100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#row:hover #colChild{
  background-color:red
}

#row:hover {
  background-color:pink
}

#col{
  padding:5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
  #colChild {
  padding:5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   #row:hover #colChild  {
        color:red;
    }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NHbn8/237/)

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/33mhdju6/3/)

```
#colChild:hover{
  background-color:red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
<div id="row">o
    <div id="col" class="col">o o
        <div id="colChild" class="col-child">o o o Turn Me Red</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#colChild:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/NHbn8/240/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selectors property to apply the effects to any partiticular div. A list of the CSS selectors has been given in the link below..
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp